# How do I add an include directory from outside the root folder with CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

This is my first CMakeLists.txt code:

```
#cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (project)

add_subdirectory(src)

include_directories(${/path_to_directory}/include)
```

And this is the CMakeLists.txt in the subdirectory

```
set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-WALL -g")

file(GLOB SRCS *.cpp *.hpp *.h)

add_executable(source ${SRCS})
```

I'm still unable to include the path_to_directory in my project

edit: This didn't work either:

```
file(GLOB mylib *.cpp *.hpp *.h)

add_executable(includeSource ${mystuff})
target_include_directories(
    mystuff
    PUBLIC ${path_to_directory}/include
)
```

Comment: Do you mean `${path_to_include}/include` instead of `${/path_to_include}/include`? What does `message("${path_to_include}")` display? What does `message("${INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES}")` display (after doing the `include_directories`)?

Answer (score 1):

Even if the question is not clear, I guess you want `target_include_directories` ([here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_include_directories.html) the documentation) instead of `include_directories`.

From the documentation:

> Specify include directories or targets to use when compiling a given target.

You can use it as:

```
target_include_directories(
    your_target_name
    PUBLIC ${/path_to_directory}/include
)
```

Comment: I'm apparently doing it wrong. I tried: 
file(GLOB mylib *.cpp *.hpp *.h)
add_executable(includeSource ${mystuff})
target_include_directories(
    mystuff
    PUBLIC ${path_to_directory}/include
)

Answer (score 1):

According to your first two codes, I understand your executable `source` doesn't compile because your compiler doesn't find the include files from `${/path_to_directory}/include`.

On this assumption, I can say you misplaced `include_directories(${/path_to_directory}/include)`, it should be in the CMakeLists.txt of subdirectory.

The [documentation of include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include_directories.html) will help you to understand :

> The include directories are added to the `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` directory property for the current CMakeLists file. They are also added to the `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` target property for each target in the current CMakeLists file. The target property values are the ones used by the generators.

Otherwise, you can replace `include_directories(${/path_to_directory}/include)` by `target_include_directories(source PUBLIC ${/path_to_directory}/include)` in your main CMakeLists.txt as @skypjack suggest. It'll impact the source target in the CMakeLists.txt of subdirectory.

---

**Additionnal comments and advise**

1. You want to compile c++ source files but you define CMAKE_C_FLAGS and not CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS.
2. `set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-Wall -g")` is dangerous if you previously set CMAKE_C_FLAGS. Prefer `set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wall -g")`
3. `file(GLOB ...)` isn't recommended to find source files. [See the documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/file.html) :

> We do not recommend using GLOB to collect a list of source files from your source tree. If no CMakeLists.txt file changes when a source is added or removed then the generated build system cannot know when to ask CMake to regenerate.

4. If your main CMakeLists.txt is as simple as you show, `add_subdirectory` is useless. You can do everything in only one main CMakeLists.txt